# jQuery/Javascript - "is not a function error" but the function is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

Hi i have this piece of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('#invite').on('click',function(){
            if(!$('#invite').hasClass('disabled') ){
                invite($("#email").val());
            }
        });
        $('#email').on('keyup',function(e){
            if(e.which == 13 && !$('#invite').hasClass('disabled') ){
                invite($("#email").val());
            }
        });


    });
    function loading(){

        window.loading = setInterval(function(){
        $(".logo img").fadeTo(500,0.1).fadeTo(550,1);
    },1600); 

    }
    function unloading(){
      $('.logo img').fadeTo(0,1);
      clearTimeout(window.loading);
    }
    function invite(_email){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:_config_base_url+'/invite/get_invite',
            data:{email:_email},
            dataType:'json',
            error:function(){
                unloading();
                $("#invite").removeClass('disabled');
               notify("Sorry an error occured, please try again later",2000);
                $("input").focusout();
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                loading();
                notify_destroy();
                $("#invite").addClass('disabled');
                $("input").focusout();
            },
            success:function(json){
                unloading();
                $('body').trigger('focus');
                $("#invite").removeClass('disabled');

                if(json.error == 'yes'){

                    notify(json.error_message,false,false);
                }else{
                    $("#email").val("");
                    notify(json.confirm_message,false,'notify-info');
                }

                $("input").focusout();
            }

        });
    }
    </script>
```

when i launch the ajax request for the first time, everythings works perfect.

But, when i try re-launch the request it always returns : **"error: loading is not a function"** and the code line involved is this one:

```
 beforeSend:function(){
                loading();
```

i have no idea what's happening there :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.loading = setInterval(function(){`

In the above line in function `loading`, `loading` is being redefined to setInterval return value because of which `loading` is no longer a function after the first invocation.

Comment: yep changed to **window.load** and it works, you rock! thanks dude